# Is there a tool to optically extract a valid UML from the Image of a UML ? (objects, relationships, etc.)

Tags: ocr, uml

I was searching for this too. I found mention of three tools but none seem available for public use or downloadable :

1- IMG2UML : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261493373_Extracting_UML_models_from_images

2- Tahitu : 
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Tahuti%3A-a-geometrical-sketch-recognition-system-for-Hammond-Davis/6cfb862a3c4af3817a44d70fad87a9fa7e74b9dc

3- UML Sketch Recognizer : http://dspace.unipampa.edu.br/bitstream/riu/884/1/UML%20Sketch%20Recognizer%20um%20aplicativo%20para%20reconhecimento%20de%20esbo%C3%A7os%20de%20diagramas%20de%20classe%20em%20fotos.pdf